# Rails 3 Search: Searchlogic vs Thinking_Sphinx

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx, searchlogic

In the past, I have used thinking_sphinx with Rails 2.3 and I found no problems with it. Is it worth considering a new search option?

What are the differences between searchlogic and thinking_sphinx?  Is there a better alternative for Rails 3?  I am keeping my options open at the moment and I am looking for suggestions.

The search functionality will need to perform full text search, efficiently and would probably be better if results were indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for thinking sphinx. I have used **searchlogic** in 2.3.x apps but I couldn't use it for Rails 3 although it's probably working now. And remember that searchlogic isn't designed for full text searching.

The helpers for sorting are helpful. But in my opinion nothing beats full text search.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Sunspot - https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot

It uses the Apache Solr search engine and works well in Rails 3.